# Display full directory in ArcMap (10) recent file list in File Menu?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap

thought this would be a pretty basic question, but I haven't found anything here or on the ESRI forums on the topic.

Is there any way to change the number of characters displayed for the file pathways listed in the File Menu list of recently used mxd files?

The obvious solution is to create shorter file names, but sometimes that's not as easy you might think!

Hover-over functionality for that list would be an ideal, long-term solution that I'd like to see, but that's neither here nor there...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best you can probably do is to look at the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Recent File List` registry key in RegEdit which is where ArcMap stores the most recently used file list.

Comment: Thanks. This seems consistent with everything else I've read relating to the recent file list. Not sure if I really want to fiddle with that registry without knowing more about it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Or submit it to ideas.esri.com for the next release.

Comment: I'll vote it up there if I see it. :-)